# CSS Compatibility between IE8, Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, safari

I am writing a JSP page. I need to have a table. One of the statements is:

```
<tr class="recordTr_SubGroup">
```

where `recordTr_SubGroup` is in a file style.css:

```
.recordTr_SubGroup {   
    background-color:#81BEF7;
    cursor: default;
}
```

I intend to highlight the row with the color. But finally, it happens correctly only in IE8. Firefox, Chrome and Safari cannot produce the same effect for the  within the

Anyone can help?

Comment: Please use the code-formatting format prescribed by SO. Indent your code with 4 spaces and put backticks around inline code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have a background colours set on one of the table layers or elements in front of the `<tr>`, so the other browsers are not showing the tr background colour since it has been effectively papered over. IE is showing it due to some other flaw - possibly it has been nudged into quirks mode.

Check there are no layers in front with a background color, double check the `<td>` doesn't by setting it to `background-color: transparent`.

See [W3C tables diagram](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-layers) for a description of how background colours should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a class to each cell, like:

```
<tr><td class="recordTr_SubGroup"></td><td class="recordTr_SubGroup"></td></tr>
```

Or change css to following:

```
tr.recordTr_SubGroup td {background-color:#81BEF7; cursor: default; }
```

Comment: <table class="recordTable" width='100%'>
<tr> 
  <th width='5%' align='left' class="recordTh">No</th>
</tr>
<tr class="recordTr_SubGroup">
  <td width='5%' align='center' class="recordTd">
  <td width='5%' align='center' class="recordTd">
  <td width='5%' align='center' class="recordTd">
</tr>